# drawing a grid in jScrollPane

Tags: java, jscrollpane

i want to draw a grid,that consists of nodes(circles) and every circle is connected with all its neighbors.
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kbi1.png)

i want to add the nodes dynamically,so i have to draw them in a scrollPanel.

i have tried to make jPanel with gridLayout,and add ellipse(as component) to every jPanel, and then add them to jScrollPanel,but the the size of the components gets smaller.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJz0J.png)

can anybody help?
thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure, a `Canvas` was used.

Comment: does the canvas support scrolling when the grid gets bigger?

Comment: You can put the canvas into a `JScrollPane`.